# Shell script garbling text in email

Tags: bash, shell

Am using script below to email me when RAID status is not "optimal".

The echo commands within such as:

```
echo $(/usr/local/RAID\ Web\ Console\ 2/StorCLI/storcli64 /c0 /eall /sall show)
```

generate an email with unformatted text such as:

```
Drive Information : ================= ----------------------------------------------------------------------- EID:Slt DID State DG Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model Sp ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 16:0 31 Onln 0 5.456 TB SAS HDD N N 512B ST6000NM0034 U 16:1 30 Onln 0 5.456 TB SAS HDD N N 512B ST6000NM0034 U 16:2 29 Onln 0 5.456 TB SAS HDD N N 512B ST6000NM0034 U 16:3 34 Onln 0 5.456 TB SAS HDD N N 512B ST6000NM0034 U 16:4 33 Onln 0 5.456 TB SAS HDD N N 512B ST6000NM0034 U 16:5 32 Onln 0 5.456 TB SAS HDD N N 512B ST6000NM0034 U 16:6 37 Onln 0 5.456 TB SAS HDD N N 512B ST6000NM0034 U 16:7 36 Onln 0 5.456 TB SAS HDD N N 512B ST6000NM0034 U 16:8 35 Onln 0 5.456 TB SAS HDD N N 512B ST6000NM0034 U 16:9 38 Onln 0 5.456 TB SAS HDD N N 512B ST6000NM0034 U 16:10 41 Onln 0 5.456 TB SAS HDD N N 512B ST6000NM0034 U 16:11 40 Onln 0 5.
```

Rather than:

```
Drive Information :
=================

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model            Sp 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
16:0     31 Onln   0 5.456 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST6000NM0034     U  
16:1     30 Onln   0 5.456 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST6000NM0034     U  
16:2     29 Onln   0 5.456 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST6000NM0034     U  
16:3     34 Onln   0 5.456 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST6000NM0034     U  
16:4     33 Onln   0 5.456 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST6000NM0034     U  
16:5     32 Onln   0 5.456 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST6000NM0034     U  
16:6     37 Onln   0 5.456 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST6000NM0034     U  
16:7     36 Onln   0 5.456 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST6000NM0034     U  
16:8     35 Onln   0 5.456 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST6000NM0034     U  
16:9     38 Onln   0 5.456 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST6000NM0034     U  
16:10    41 Onln   0 5.456 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST6000NM0034     U  
16:11    40 Onln   0 5.456 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST6000NM0034     U  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Surely there's something dumb I'm not doing here! Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CLISTAT=$(/usr/local/RAID\ Web\ Console\ 2/StorCLI/storcli64 /c0 /vall show | grep RAID6 |awk '{ print $3 }')

if [ "$CLISTAT" = "Optl" ]; then

        echo "RAID status is optimal. All is good!"
        exit 0
else
        (
echo "From: admin@example.org"
echo "To: admin@example.org"
echo "Subject: RAID status alert on server.example.org !!"
echo "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)"
echo "X-MSMail-Priority: High"
echo "Importance: High"
echo ""
date
echo
echo "The RAID status on Socs-Stats is not optimal!"
echo " "
echo "Hard Drive details:"
echo " "
echo $(/usr/local/RAID\ Web\ Console\ 2/StorCLI/storcli64 /c0 /eall /sall show)
echo " "
echo " "
echo "Virtual Drive details:"
echo $(/usr/local/RAID\ Web\ Console\ 2/StorCLI/storcli64 /c0 /vall show)
echo  "----------------------------------------------------------------" 

) | /sbin/sendmail -it 

exit 2

fi
```

Comment: You don't need to use a command substitution to capture the output of a command, just to pass that to `echo`.

Comment: @chepner sorry, I don't understand your suggestion...for example?

Comment: Don't use `echo $(foo ...)`; just use `foo ...`. (This doesn't fix the error, just a matter of normal practice.)

Comment: @chepner gotcha, thanks. But that doesn't fix the formatting issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put quotes around command substitutions :

```
echo "$(/usr/local/RAID\ Web\ Console\ 2/StorCLI/storcli64 /c0 /eall /sall show)"
echo " "
echo " "
echo "Virtual Drive details:"
echo "$(/usr/local/RAID\ Web\ Console\ 2/StorCLI/storcli64 /c0 /vall show)"
```

Comment: actually that does work, thanks! I needed to make sure the Content-Type: text/plain and now it's working. Thanks!